# Tool name: Hoe with spikes

Tags: tools

What is the technical name for this style of hoe?

[image]

<sup>Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/p4zuzc/unlike_you_loners_i_actually_have_a_hoe/)</sup>

---

The reason I ask is:

I'm trying to find this style of hoe for sale in Ontario, Canada.

But when I google "hoe", the results only have the spade portion of the hoe, not the spikes.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that there's a single technical name for the tool, which derived from a two-prong/two-spike variant of a mattock. I've seen:

- [Weeding Hoe with Mattock](https://www.tompress.co.uk/A-10001272-weeding-hoe-with-mattock-and-fork-small-model.aspx)
- [Garden Mattock](https://rawtools.org/product/garden-mattock/)
- [Gardening Hoe Mattock](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/40cm-Gardening-Hoe-Mattock-Two-Jaw-Multi-Function-Wooden-Rake-Handle-Garden-Tool/121668164480)

There is also a "Mattock and Fork" with three spikes instead of two.